# What type of comprehension is this?

Tags: python

I came across the following Python code and am having trouble understanding it:

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(length))
```

The `for` loop tells me it's a comprehension, but of what type? It's not a list comprehension, because the `[]` are missing (unless there's a special syntax at work here). I tried to work it out by running

```
random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(length)
```

directly in the interpreter but got syntax error at `for`.

I did some digging around and came to a not-so-sure conclusion that this is what's called a generator comprehension, but I didn't find any examples that look like this one; they all use the `()` notation for creating the generator object.

So, is it like `join()` works on iterators (and therefore generators) and we actually have a generator syntax here? If yes, can we omit the surrounding `()` when creating generator objects in function calls?

Comment: "So, is it like join() works on iterators (and therefore generators) and we actually have a generator syntax here":`Yes`. "can we omit the surrounding () when creating generator objects in function calls?": `if the function works on iterables.`

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks! Yes, I verified that by running a few more examples. The syntax is really tricky, though! :D

Comment: @ankush981 I would suggest you to look at generator unpacking as well. For example `print(*(i for i in range(10)))`

Comment: @SayandipDutta Wow! Another brain twister! Will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

1. you need `join()` because the list contains characters, and you want to get a string,  hence `join()`
2. `random.choice()` selects random character from the argument list
3. the argument list contains ASCII upper/lower case characters and digits
4. the length of the resulting string is `length`

Summing up all together, this line of code generates a random string with length `length` that contains upper/lower case letters and numbers.

This is a plain old list comprehension, just the `[]` are missing because not required when you use `join()`

Comment: I think OP knows about points 1 to 4 you have mentioned. Also there are many differences between list comprehension and generator expression. So "plain old list comprehension, just the [] are missing" seems like an over-simplification. Rather, one can argue list comprehensions are plain old generator expressions, just the `[]` added.

Comment: @SayandipDutta "plain old generator expressions, just the [] added" actually look like this: `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa776782aa0>]` =)

Comment: @lenik "This is a plain old list comprehension" Really? Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that it's a generator expression that can be used as needed. So, the `[]` produces a list from it, whereas other functions may just iterate over it? Your comment above does say `[<generator>]`, which makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It creates an iterator, much like in a list comprehension. Take this example from [pythonwiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators#CA-6021c335e902d0510d5cf727f4891fa800d440d6_1):

```
# list comprehension
doubles = [2 * n for n in range(50)]

# same as the list comprehension above
doubles = list(2 * n for n in range(50))
```

Both are list comprehensions, but the former case is more familiar. I believe your example relies on the latter case. The wiki I linked calls this a generator expression.

Comment: Not sure how this relates to my question. In your example, there's an explicit call to `list()`, which doesn't even result in a generator but a list that is computed eagerly. i.e., `list(2 * n for n in range(50))` is a list, whereas `(2 * n for n in range(50)` is a generator. But what I mention is different from both of these. Hopefully you can see that now.

Comment: It is a generator. The list function uses that generator to then compute the list. @ankush981

Comment: @ankush981 it will work with `sum` as well. Basically, any function that takes iterables as input.

Comment: Try interpreting: `print(i for i in range(10))`. It will print that the argument is a generator. @ankush981